# I’m a fashion designer looking to move into UX, should I do a masters or a short course?

Tags: user-centered-design

I’m currently a fashion designer looking to move into UX design. I am adept at adobe suite and have a great interest in psychology and sociology.
I’ve found myself bored recently with the ongoing cycle of fashion trends and what seems like the growing lack of appreciation for designers within retail.
I’ve been drawn to UX because of the apparent deeper connection to design and customer. I love the idea of researching Customers and analysing data however for the last 6 years I have been frustrated with lack of this in fashion.

I’ve read a lot on these forums stating that short courses like general assembly or MA courses are not necessary however I’m wondering if my experience isn’t tailored (buh dum tish) necessarily to ux design as a lot of people seem to be from computer science or graphic design backgrounds.

I also need to buy a computer in order to study further, would you consider laptops a necessity or is the work mainly done at home, therefore a iMac would be sufficient? Alternative would be getting a screen etc for a smaller 13 inch MacBook. (Sorry I know this is mundane but It’s a big investment for me during this pandemic!)

Coding, where do I start? I only ask as I’ve read that a good understanding is necessary but an in-depth knowledge is worthwhile if you consider specialising or working with smaller teams.

Finally, how is it working in ux design? I’ve heard it’s ever evolving which is great however are staff valued ?
In fashion redundancies are often and it seems to be a dying trade.
I’m looking for a job I can get my teeth into and feel like I’m constantly learning.

Thanks in advance for your help!
I live in hackney London so if anyone fancies meeting for a coffee that’d be great, I’m less boring in person and the coffee would be on me!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is related to a career in UX rather than a UX design question, but I would encourage you to reach out to various people in this community through chat, ask similar questions in reddit or Quora (where there are already lots of really good discussion and answers).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're a professional with a college degree and have experience dealing with the business end of things: managers, deadlines, customers which would mean that you have a lot of the soft skills that will make you stand out when interviewing.

The first thing is to read. Everyone will have a different set of books, articles and websites but I would start with the classics and don't forget that in the 1990s and early 2000's this field was called Information Architecture.

Then work on projects - create your own, that's what people do in college. Try your hand whiteboarding, at use cases, user personas, and of course the design process itself: from low fidelity to as high as you can produce. The one thing you're missing out on is the collaborative environment and professional guidance - but I would leave individual classes for last, after you've put in real work on your own.

Read. Make sketches,  ask detailed questions of this group and others. This will force you to be able to articulate the problem as opposed to simply crying "help, it doesn't look good."

Since you're adept at the Adobe Suite I would recommend being at least somewhat comfortable with HTML and CSS. It's very frustrating working with people who are working on responsive sites and who don't grasp divs, and that design elements cannot simply be moved from "container" to "container" at whim.

As a fashion designer you know that your designs have to be sewn using real world fabrics and tools. The same is true with your application design. It will need to be built according to the limitations of the existing technology. Understanding HTML (and CSS, .js ...) is understanding the materials with which your design is being made.

Two books, among many to start with are:

- Dan Norman's *Design of Everyday Things*
- Gothelf and Seiden's *Lean UX*

Comment: Information Architecture was a brief period, about a particular set of issues, before that it was Usability, and  before that HCI (Human Computer Interaction).  I wouldn't read Don as an intro book, there's a large booklist on here which is about the best I know.

Comment: Yah. I'm old enough to remember when Jakob Nielsen's "Designing Web Usability" was the bible.